# Constructing a Neural Network for Multiple Outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

My input data is as follows:

```
AT  V   AP  RH  PE
14.96   41.76   1024.07 73.17   463.26
25.18   62.96   1020.04 59.08   444.37
5.11    39.4    1012.16 92.14   488.56
20.86   57.32   1010.24 76.64   446.48
10.82   37.5    1009.23 96.62   473.9
26.27   59.44   1012.23 58.77   443.67
15.89   43.96   1014.02 75.24   467.35
9.48    44.71   1019.12 66.43   478.42
14.64   45  1021.78 41.25   475.98
....................................
```

I am basically working on Python using Tensorflow Library.
    As of now,I have a linear model,which is working fine for 4 inputs and 1 output.This is basically a regression problem.
    For e.g: After training my neural network with sufficient data(say if the size of data is some 10000), then while training my neural network,if I am passing the values 45,30,25,32,as inputs , it is returning the value 46 as Output.

I basically have two queries:

1. As of now, in my code, I am using the parameters
   `training_epochs` , `learning_rate` etc. I am as of now giving the
   value of `training_epochs` as 10000.So, when I am testing my neural
   network by passing four input values, I am getting the output as
   some 471.25, while I expect it to be 460.But if I am giving the
   value of `training_epochs` as 20000, instead of 10000, I am getting
   my output value as 120.5, which is not at all close when compared to
   the actual value "460".

**Can you please explain, how can one chose the values of `training_epochs` and `learning_rate`(or any other parameter values) in my code, so that I can get good accuracy.**

2. Now, the second issue is, my neural network as of now is working
   only for linear data as well as only for 1 output. **If I want to have
   3 inputs and 2 outputs and also a non-linear model, what are the
   possible changes I can make in my code?**

I am posting my code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rng = np.random


# In[180]:

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 10000
display_step = 1000


# In[171]:

# Read data from CSV

df = pd.read_csv("H:\MiniThessis\Sample.csv")


# In[173]:

# Seperating out dependent & independent variable

train_x = df[['AT','V','AP','RH']]
train_y = df[['PE']]
trainx = train_x.as_matrix().astype(np.float32)
trainy = train_y.as_matrix().astype(np.float32)
# In[174]:

n_input = 4
n_classes = 1
n_hidden_1 = 5
n_samples = 9569

# tf Graph Input
#Inserts a placeholder for a tensor that will be always fed.
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])

# Set model weights
W_h1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1]))
W_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_classes]))
b_h1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1]))
b_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))


# In[175]:

# Construct a linear model
layer_1 = tf.matmul(x, W_h1) + b_h1
layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_1, W_out) + b_out


# In[176]:

# Mean squared error
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(out_layer-y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
# Gradient descent
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)


# In[177]:

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


# In[181]:

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: trainx,y: trainy})

        # Display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c))

    print("Optimization Finished!")
    training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: trainx,y: trainy})
    print(training_cost)

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(out_layer, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    best = sess.run([out_layer], feed_dict=
    {x:np.array([[14.96,41.76,1024.07,73.17]])})
    print(correct_prediction)

    print(best)
```

Answer (score 1):

1.you can adjust these following lines;

```
# In general baises are either initialized as zeros or not zero constant, but not Gaussian 
b_h1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hidden_1]))
b_out = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_classes]))

# MSE error
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(out_layer-y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
```

Also, Feed the data as mini batches; as the optimizer you are using is tuned for minibatch optimization; feeding the data as a whole doesn't result in optimal performance.

2.
for multiple ouputs you need to change only the `n_classes` and the cost fucntion (`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`). Also the model you defined here isn't linear; as you are using the non linear activation function `tf.nn.relu`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I tried changing my cost function from reduce mean square to Softmax, i got this following error           print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c))
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__ ....i tried printing my cost functions when it was reduce mean square and softmax i got following     RMS - > Tensor("truediv:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).   softmax -> Tensor("Reshape_2:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32).

Comment: the error here is just a normal python syntax problem. you need to fix your `print` statement

Comment: Ishant, I made the following changes in the code,which I posted in my post...train_x = df[['AT','V','AP']]
train_y = df[['RH','PE']] ; n_input = 3
n_classes = 2;  cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=out_layer, labels=y)); after this, If I am training my neural network and trying to test my neural network with one of the train datas,I am really getting wierd result,bcoz at each 1000th Epoch,cost value is very high,almost 4803645..Could you please let me know about this? I think,I am not passing correct arguments in cost function..Waiting for your reply

Comment: You need t feed the data as mini batches, feeding the whole dataset is not a good idea. also the labels=y should be a one_hot vector; ALSO one input should not have multiple output nodes, if your input have multiple output, combine their features into one output; here by multiple ouputs, i mean multi class classification.

Comment: Hi Ishant,I will look into feeding the data as mini batches.  I am not able to understand the construction of my cost function. Could you please explain in detail, the changes ,I can make in my code,so that it would function for multiple outputs. As in my data,I have 5 columns, I want to consider first three columns as input and next two columns as output.This problem is not classification right? Is n't it regressive problem?