# Multioutput Neural network models

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, lstm, tensorflow2.0, feed-forward

I have a dataset (dataframe) with 15 input variables and 10 output variables which can be either categorical or numeric variables. ( I .I treated in learn how to do that in both cases using tensorflow or keras).
I want to develop a deep learning model that can, based on a vector (1,15), be able to obtain an output one (1,10).
Input=[[1,12,3,0.3.....]] numerical variables.
Output =[[0.3,0.2,1,3....]] As a numerical output or [[1,2,1,0..]] as a categorical variable

I have reviewed and an lstm or cnn model could be used for my case, but when structuring it it has been somewhat confusing to develop a model that generates an output vector of that length, as in typical cases where for n inputs only the prediction o is performed.  classification for an attribute or output variable.  Some have an idea of ​​how to develop such a structure that can have multiple outputs

Comment: Hi @Mllearner, found similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370218/multi-output-neural-network-by-tensorflow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45721646/constructing-a-neural-network-for-multiple-outputs), these might help you. Thanks!